# How to make Tensorboard Image summary to show orderly

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I made grouping MNIST images and made tf.image_summary(...).
I made image summary for each group.
e.g 
Test Image : 1
Test Image : 2

When I run Tensorboard images, it does not show as I order.
How to make to show tensorboard images orderly.

[Tensorboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hehx6.png)

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always orders alphabetically. This is a bit hacky, but if you pre-pend alphabetical ordering to the start of the image tag, then you can control the order.